Access bound data in join
How can I access the bound data within the enter (say) callback of .join? Assume the following use case. In my data I have a slot (n) which is used to create an object. I thought I could use .datum() to get the bound data, but apparently it just returns the first element.
I know that the class is an overkill here, but let's assume that this part is nothing I cna easily change.


class Rects {
  #n;
  #colorMap = d3.scaleOrdinal();
  #domain;
  constructor(n) {
    this.#n = n;
    this.#domain = [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => i);
    this.#colorMap
      .domain(this.#domain)
      .range(['purple', 'forestgreen', 'orange']);
  }
  
  draw(selection) {
    const height = 20,
      width = 20,
      margin = 20;
    selection.append('svg')
      .attr('width', this.#n * width + margin)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin + ',0)')
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.#domain)
      .join('rect')
      .attr('x', (i) => width * i)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('fill', (d) => this.#colorMap(d))
  }
}  
  
const data = [{n: 3, text: 'some text'}, {n:2, text: 'some other text'}];
 
d3.select('#root')
  .selectAll('li')
  .data(data)
  .join((enter) => {
    const n = enter.datum().n;
    const r = new Rects(n);
    enter.append('li')
      .text((d) => 'There should be `d.n=' + d.n + '` rects:')
      .call(r.draw.bind(r))
  })
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<ul id="root">
</ul>




enter.data() will return the array of data bound to the enter selection.

Yes I saw that, but how could I use that to extract the slot in this case?

I am not sure whether this is the canonical solution, but at least it works. So instead of putting the logic in the enter callback, we simply return the selection and use each on the selection. Within each we have access to the current datum and can call the constructor of the class with the corresponding value of n.


class Rects {
  #n;
  #colorMap = d3.scaleOrdinal();
  #domain;
  constructor(n) {
    this.#n = n;
    this.#domain = [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => i);
    this.#colorMap
      .domain(this.#domain)
      .range(['purple', 'forestgreen', 'orange']);
  }
  
  draw(selection) {
    const height = 20,
      width = 20,
      margin = 20;
    selection.append('svg')
      .attr('width', this.#n * width + margin)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin + ',0)')
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.#domain)
      .join('rect')
      .attr('x', (i) => width * i)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('fill', (d) => this.#colorMap(d))
  }
}  
  
const data = [{n: 3, text: 'some text'}, {n:2, text: 'some other text'}];
 
const enter = d3.select('#root')
  .selectAll('li')
  .data(data)
  .join();
  
enter.each(function (d, i) {
    const enter = d3.select(this);
    const n = d.n;
    const r = new Rects(n);
    enter.append('li')
      .text((d) => 'There should be `d.n=' + d.n + '` rects:')
      .call(r.draw.bind(r))
  })
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<ul id="root">
</ul>



